# How to do lead history reporting in Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, force.com

I would like to measure the amount of time it takes a rep to open a new lead but cannot figure out how to run a report using the time component of the date / time stamp in the Lead history object. I can see the time when I do a simple "show lead history" but cannot figure out how to run a report against that field.

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can report on this easily :/ I'd love to be proven wrong though.

When you have only a hammer everything looks like a nail, eh?

You can get the day of the opening in the report, but not really "seconds between opening and lead creation". I've checked and it seems you can't even cheat by creating a workflow that would fire on marking the lead as opened.

[image: sample lead history report]

---

If you're fine with exporting the details of similar report to Excel and building the formulas there I'd recommend that route. If it really has to be 100% in Salesforce - have you ever used Apex and Visualforce? You could write a trigger on Leads that would detect the opening of lead and write the time difference to some custom field.

Or you could create a VF page for which code similar to this would be a data source.
For my data it outputs

> On average it took 160917287 seconds to for user 005... to open 2
>   leads.

(I know it's a huge number, they're from 2007).

```
Map<Id, Long> timeCounter = new Map<Id, Long>(); // Counter how much time has passed between lead creation and opening of the record for each lead owner
Map<Id, Integer> leadCounter = new Map<Id, Integer>(); // counter how many were actually opened

for(LeadHistory lh : [SELECT CreatedDate, OldValue, NewValue, Lead.Name, Lead.OwnerId, Lead.CreatedDate
    FROM LeadHistory
    WHERE Field = 'IsUnreadByOwner' AND Lead.isUnreadByOwner = false
    ORDER BY Lead.OwnerId
    LIMIT 1000]){

    Long timeInSeconds = (lh.CreatedDate.getTime() - lh.Lead.CreatedDate.getTime()) / 1000;
    Long totalTimeCount = timeCounter.get(lh.Lead.OwnerId);
    Integer totalLeadCount = leadCounter.get(lh.Lead.OwnerId);
    if(totalTimeCount == null){
        totalTimeCount = timeInSeconds;
        totalLeadCount = 1;
    } else {
        totalTimeCount += timeInSeconds;
        totalLeadCount += 1;
    }
    timeCounter.put(lh.Lead.OwnerId, totalTimeCount);
    leadCounter.put(lh.Lead.OwnerId, totalLeadCount);
}

for(Id userId : timeCounter.keyset()){
    Decimal avg = timeCounter.get(userId) / leadCounter.get(userId);
    System.debug('On average it took ' + avg + ' seconds to for user ' + userId + ' to open ' + leadCounter.get(userId) + ' leads.');
}
```